# firefox javascript window.open _self

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

My problem is:
When I use:

```
window.open("example.com","_self");
```

or

```
self.open("example.com");
```

or

```
window.location.href="example.com";
```

Firefox removes all menus, buttons, window's window minimization buttons, everything. Also context menu stop working, but site opens fine except this chaos, which ruins everything.

So how to fix this?

**EDIT:**
I'm using FF22, fresh install.
Looks like its not a simple case so I drop here entire code, it's slightly edited addon for creating new tabs from context menu:

```
let _ = require("l10n").get;
let winUtils = require("window-utils");
let { isBrowser } = require("api-utils/window/utils");

var delegate = {
onTrack: function (window) {
if (isBrowser(window) ){
    let menu = window.document.getElementById("tabContextMenu");
        let newtab = window.document.createElementNS("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul","menuitem");
            newtab.setAttribute("id", "contexttab-newtab");
            newtab.setAttribute("label", _("newtab_string"));
            newtab.setAttribute("accesskey", _("newtabaccesskey_string"));
            newtab.setAttribute("oncommand", "window.location.href='http://www.example.com'");
            menu.insertBefore(newtab, menu.firstChild);
        } // End isBrowser
    } // End ontrack
} // End delegate function

let tracker = new winUtils.WindowTracker(delegate);


// code to remove the menuitem when extension is disabled for satisfy requirement on AMO for pass a full review
// On uninstall the menuitem is not removed, see: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=627432

exports.onUnload = function(reason) {
    var unloader = {
        onTrack: function (window) {
            if (isBrowser(window) ){
                let menu = window.document.getElementById("tabContextMenu");
                let newtab = window.document.getElementById("contexttab-newtab");
                menu.removeChild(newtab);
            }
        }
    }; // End unloader function

    let remover = new winUtils.WindowTracker(unloader);
}
```

This is the only line I edited:

```
newtab.setAttribute("oncommand", "window.location.href='http://www.example.com'");
```

Comment: it will directly redirect you to "example.com" thats why it is not showing your menus and all..if you want to open the url at specific place of your page you can use the frame or kind of to open the url at specific place..

Comment: Which version of FF you're using? I [can't reproduce](http://jsfiddle.net/Qeagx/) this with FF24.

Comment: I updated first post.

Comment: its never really a good idea to change the window.location, best way to do it is either server side redirect or load the page using ajax or in a frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
gBrowser.loadURI('http://www.example.com');
```

works properly.

Answer (score 0):

`gBrowser.loadURI` loads a page into the selected tab I think.

If you want to open a new window you have to do it like this:

```
var url = Cc['@mozilla.org/supports-string;1'].createInstance(Ci.nsISupportsString);
url.data = 'http://www.bing.com/';
Services.ww.openWindow(null, 'chrome://browser/content/browser.xul', '_blank', 'chrome,all', url);
```

Comment: OP did not want to open a new window (hence why OP's original call was passing in `_self`).